# Upload file using file path as string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-5.0

I have local machine file path in my c# code as string only, I want to get the file details from the path and want to upload that file on server / application folder.

Path like :

> C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Image.png

Can you please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: are you using mvc or webforms?

Comment: Actually i am passing local path from my script to MVC controller and there i want to read file.

Comment: so you've already stored the file and saved the url and now you'd like to see it presented?

Comment: ok, i've updated my post to include pretty much everything it takes to upload and retrieve your pics (except for the model which is simple) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File-handling is all fairly new to me but, this is how I've done it in a recent MVC project.

**ImageController:**
this is how I'm saving the file

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["userUploadedFile"];

        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var selectAlbum = Request.Form["lstAlbums"];

        Image img = new Image();
        img.FileName = file.FileName;
        img.FileType = file.ContentType;
        img.Size = file.ContentLength;
        img.Path = "/uploads/"; //  + userName

        string relativePath = img.Path + img.FileName;
        // relativePath.Replace("/", "\\"); 
        string absolutePath = Server.MapPath(relativePath); 
        file.SaveAs(absolutePath);
        img.Path = relativePath;
        img.User = User;

        db.Images.Add(img);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

**PostController:** this is how I'm getting the image:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult ViewPost(int? id = 1) 
{              
    if (id == null)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    else 
        {
            Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
            return View(post);
        }

   }
```

**ViewPost.cshtml** And this is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<BlogEngine.Models.Post>


<table class="table">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("About this Website", "About")*@
            <a href="/posts/viewpost/?id=@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IntroText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(item.Body)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Modified)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**update based on comment:**

Try this to get a file:

```
try
    {
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" +
            @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.bmp", true);

        TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(image1);
        texture.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(texture, 
            new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 100, 100));
        formGraphics.Dispose();

    }
    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            "Please check the path.");
    }
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: hey thanks Dan for this, Its very helpful for me... having query if we have text box where i entered path only and on button click how can i upload that file in folder. so now i have only path in my c# code ?

Comment: so you're asking how to get user input from the view back to a variable in the controller so you can insert it into your file-path?

Comment: file is not loaded in my case on form. I entered only file path where file is present on local machine. Now by using that path i want to load/ read file in my controller side as in C# code and upload in server side folder.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I did vote you up by the way. Also, The reason why others were probably down-voting your question was because you didn't post any of your code along with it. Just a tip!